# Stripe array which stores each (whole) file on one disk (zfs/lvm?)

Tags: filesystems, lvm, zfs

My configuration is: two HDD drives (3TB+4TB), which I want to use as a stripe array.

I want to achieve that if one of my drive fails, half of my files (on good drive) are guaranteed to be safe. In other words, I want that each of my file will **entirely** be stored on either drive instead of being scattered over both drives (splitted by chunks).

Is this task achieveable by ZFS or by LVM?

If not, maybe other options available for that task?

Again,
I want combine two drives into one big partition. And I want to access files stored on 1st drive, when 2nd is off.

Comment: ZFS best guess: setup both drives as mirror, enable compression and hope that you achieve 2x ratio. LVM is a volume manager and it is up to the filesystem where the blocks are stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after some research, I've found what I wanted.

The right keyword for it would be "union mount".

There is some options for Linux:

- OverlayFS
- UnionFS, aufs
- unionfs-fuse, funionfs, mhddfs and [mergerfs](https://github.com/trapexit/mergerfs)

My final choice is **mergerfs**. I'll explain why.

OverlayFS is built into kernel (and this is a big advantage). But. By design, it always writes to one partition, leaving another untouched. It is convenient when you need to make read-only partition writeable (as it done in LiveCDs), but I want to write to both partitions equally.

Next is UnionFS and aufs. Not sure about UnionFS, but aufs needs to rebuild the kernel (to apply aufs patches) which is undesirable.

Third option is FUSE-based software. Some of them (funionfs) I've doesn't find in my distro's repository, some of them (unionfs-fuse) have version number 1.0, so I assume it pretty raw.

So I've tried mergerfs and found no drawbacks (for my use-case). It can use logical volumes with any filesystem and any size. Files are not scattered by pieces over all drives (as in RAID0, lvm and zfs). Some data is still accessible if some drives (less than total count) are became unavailable. Balancing! (new files will be written to drive that has more free space). And no need to rebuild the kernel :)

Comment: So, for data so critical that you *have* to have access to at least half of it should a drive fail, you pick a user-space file system with a very small installed user base that's been around only two years or so?  You *do* have backups, right?

Comment: Well, my data is not so critical, and I've chosen this solution (over RAID1, 5 or 6) not because I think it be safer for my data. Of course not.
I doesn't need redundancy as in RAID1 or RAID5/6. For my task I could have used RAID0 (by means of mdadm or LVM or ZFS), but "losing all my not so critical data" is not the same thing as "losing half of my not so critical data" (or one third of data if I'll add third disk in future). Another reason is that this method is much more flexible than mentioned above techniques. And yes, for data that I'm considering critical, I do use backups :)

Answer (score 0):

The only possible configuration in ZFS would be to create two separate pools out of one disk each.

If you instead join them in a single pool, they are striped in a way that loss of one disk is fatal for the whole pool. If you don't use 'copies=2', loss of a single file would also be fatal.

Lambert's suggestion is a nice workaround, but as you would have 2x3TB instead of 3+4TB, you would need more than 2.0 compression (which is already quite hard to achieve for single user systems).